# Prove this equation involving Landau Notation

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I started working through [this](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/M_Mathematics/MT_Number%20theory/Chen%20Elementary.pdf) work about number theory, but I've never really used Landau notation before so I am sometimes struggling to understand the steps used in the proofs. Specifically in Theorem $1.8$ in the last equation I believe it is asserted that
$$
 \int_Y^\infty\frac{u-\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^2}du = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{Y})
$$
How can I see this to be the case?

Comment: It is **Landau** $O$-notation. Named after [Edmund Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Landau). Check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The tag [tag:lambda-calculus] is not appropriate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh my mistake! Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's between $0$ and $\int_Y^\infty\tfrac{1}{u^2}du=\tfrac1Y$.